# What GPU culling techniques are appropriate for voxel spheres other than octrees?

Tags: procedural-generation, voxels, dynamic-mesh

I'm creating a dynamic smooth-voxel based world in the shape of a sphere. Right now my current approach is to spherize a cube, generate voxel terrain on each of the six patches, and then use octrees to cull the data further.

Octree's are best served with cubes. Is there a better system for storing/accessing data in a sphere? I've heard some talk of Octree's not being the best way to store voxel data, even for cube worlds. How can this be? What would be better? A Hash Table?  Surely multidimensional arrays wouldn't be faster? Perhaps it's just more of a design decision than performance? As in, maybe someone didn't like chunks popping in so they would rather load individual rows and columns?

If it matters, I'm probably going to keep relevant geometry in GPU memory and stream in the surrounding area over time as the player gets closer to it from main memory. I bring this up because I'm really not sure if GPU memory benefits from any particular structure. All I really know is that the parallel powers of the GPU are, well, unparalleled (I had to). How can I tap into that?

Comment: I think youre confusing the visible shape of the tile with the space partitioning technique. They are two different things.

Comment: They aren't mutually exclusive though either. The squareness of the shape naturally lends itself to the shape of the space partitioning technique, no? Everything is reduced to a triangle. Two triangles are a square. Sure, I can use a quadtree with pentagon tiles but... a square would work best since they are squares in the mathematical sense.

Comment: But the shape of the sphere wont easily lend to any space partitioning technique, and you want to use spheres.

I think that what you are looking for are occlusion algorithms? Those are better for voxels I think.

Comment: I guess when I thought about it I realized that much of the top-level Octree nodes would be lost to empty spaces. To a degree, I need some empty nodes nodes because players are able to build upwards, but that still leaves a lot blank.

Perhaps it's not so much a spatial partition I'm looking for, but wondering about if there's a fast way to cull all nodes X units away from the center of the planet, and if that might increase performance.

Obviously there's no really no way to store a circle in memory without using a square. I see how that's shape independent.

Comment: Or is there a way? Say I had a multidimensional array that stored a square sprite and that I was using 20 x 20 of those square sprites to make a circle. I could at least make the array smaller by removing the empty elements and rely on an algorithm to put the elements back into their proper shape. Less memory but more math.

It's okay if that doesn't make sense to anyone else but me, lol. Just crazy talk. This is how new stuff gets invented. Thinking outside the box (more puns!?)

Comment: I think... I think I just described sparse octrees. Sparse octrees are the same as regular octrees, except the empty data is culled and stored in leaf-lists. BRILLIANT. I invented something existed before I knew it existed.